# Log4j SMTP Appender

Tags: java, log4j

Hi I am a novice and the application I am currently coding for uses struts 1.2 and java. We currently use Log4j for log files but I need to implement SMTP Appender so that our errors are emailed to us.

I've tried everything to get errors to be emailed with no luck. Below is our log4j.properties file.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
log4j.rootLogger= INFO, stdout, logfile, mail

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n

# Keep three backup files
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=C:/LOGS/WIRE.log
log4j.appender.logfile.MaxFileSize=2048KB

#email appender
log4j.appender.mail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.mail.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPHost=smtp.serverhere.com
log4j.appender.mail.From=johndoe@serverhere.com
log4j.appender.mail.To=johndoe@serverhere.com
log4j.appender.mail.Subject=Application Error
log4j.appender.mail.threshold=error
log4j.appender.mail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mail.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p [%c] - <%m>%n


# Hibernates use of the org.apache classes spews out stuff like mad.
log4j.logger.org.apache=INFO

# Springframework is very talkative too.
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO

# acegisecurity 
#log4j.logger.org.acegisecurity = INFO

# Quartz trigger checking 
log4j.logger.org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore=INFO
#log4j.logger.org.springframework.scheduling.quartz=INFO
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, the appender only sends an email when something is logged at the [ERROR or FATAL levels](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html).
As a side note, it appears that your threshold property may have improper case. I believe:

```
log4j.appender.mail.threshold=error
```

should be

```
log4j.appender.mail.Threshold=error
```

Edit...

Log4j can be put into debug mode by configuring the [log4j.debug configuration property](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html). This might provide some output regarding the SMTP appender.

Comment: I am trying to get it to email us of any ERROR or Fatal levels. I attempted your suggestion, but didn't help. Is there any type of logs for log4j for debugging purposes?

Comment: @Brian I added info about "debug" mode. We have recently switched to logback (which was also written by Ceki Gülcü). Having used it for a couple of months, I much prefer it over log4j: http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html

Answer (score 0):

Define the root logger in error level and override this for selected packages. The mail appender will remain in the error level.

```
# Log appenders
#log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, FILE, MAIL

# Log levels
log4j.logger.com.example.application=INFO
log4j.logger.com.example.application.package=DEBUG


# CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5r %-5p [%t] %c{2} - %m%n
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding=UTF-8


# FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/tmp/application.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=99
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5r %-5p [%t] %c{2} - %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.Encoding=UTF-8


# MAIL
log4j.appender.MAIL=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.MAIL.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.MAIL.SMTPHost=smtp.example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.From=application@example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.To=developer@example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.Subject=Exception in Application
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5r %-5p [%t] %c{2} - %m%n
```